# mysql SELECT, divide tables into PHP arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

is it posible to create a SELECT query that give's back something like this?

```
    array (size=2)
      'table1' => 
        array (size=2)
          'column1' => int 1
          'column2' => string 'username' (length=8)
      'table2' => 
        array (size=2)
          'column1' => int 1
          'column2' => string 'username' (length=8)
```

i need to select data with a join but one of the tables have about 100 columns and i would really like them to be grouped in one array key if it is possible.

thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be possible to do so, what have you tried?

Comment: it must be handled by your application, sql result is only 1-dimensional array.

Comment: i was afraid of that, i wanted to avoid 2 select statements, thank you john woo!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a_rs = firstquery

$b_rs = secondquery

$ar = array();
$i=0
while($a_rs && $a_r = mysql_fetch_object($a_rs))
{
    foreach($a_r as $k => $v)
    {
        $ar['a'][$i][$k] = $v;
    }
     $i++;
}

$ii = 0;

while($b_rs && $b_r = mysql_fetch_object($b_rs))
{
    foreach($b_r as $k => $v)
    {
        $ar['b'][$ii][$k] = $v;
    }
    $ii++;
}

echo "<pre>".var_export($ar)."</pre>";
```